# Icon not found in WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have set `Icon= "icon.ico"` in `MainWindow.xaml` but it does not find it. I got the icon in the final build directory and in project directory. Absolut path works.

My question is: where does the Icon= "icon.ico points to from my xaml file and how to properly reference relative path?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="icon.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="icon.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

to my `.csproj`.